# Anitvirus says my program is suspicious

Tags: wpf, antivirus

I built a program in wpf visual studios and when I run it avast says suspicious program detected then closes my program.

Can I do anything to verify it, or do I have to go into avast and set it to not block my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly unblock your own program in most major Anti-virus packages (first make sure your anti-virus software is up-to-date and you have recently scanned your development machine to be sure that, in fact, there is no virus).

I don't have access to Avast, but from a support article on their website it looks like you can add your file to the "exclusions list in the File Shield".

If you intend to distribute the program, you can [submit the program](https://support.avast.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=586) as a suspected false positive to Avast.  They can unblock it with their next update if they agree it's a false positive.

Comment: I will be running this program at work for me and probably me only. No need to submit anything to avast then (I didn't know that is what I would have to do). I'll just unblock it from avast. Thanks.

Comment: Please do make sure you don't actually have a virus.